# Distribution of a variable obtained by multiplying two Gaussian distribution related terms

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given two orthogonal unit vectors **a**  $ \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and **b** $ \in \mathbb{R}^N$ such that **a**$^T$ **b** $= 0$, |**a**|$=1$, |**b**|$=1$ where **a**$^T$ means the transpose of **a**, and a vector **w**$\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times N}$. Suppose that each element in **w** follows the Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1/N)$. Define a random variable as $z =$ (**wa**)(**wb**), and what kind of distribution does $z$ follow?

I have run the Monte Carlo simulations, and it seems that $z$ follows $\mathcal{N}(0,1/N^2)$. How to evaluate such a distribution in a theoertically manner?

Comment: Assuming the elements of $\mathbf{w}$ were independent then I would have guessed $z$ would have an expectation of $0$ and variance of $1/N^2$, as you have, but $z$ would not have a normal distribution, instead having the sharply peaked distribution than you would get from the distribution of $w_1w_2$ (using the rotational symmetry of a standard multivariate normal as a guide to thinking).  Perhaps you could check the shape of the distribution of your simulations.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mIF5.png) shows the shape of a "normal product distribution" compared to a normal distribution (remembering that for your question you have to scale by a standard deviation of $\frac1N$)